# Python Sorting a text file by fields

Tags: python, class, sorting, text-files

I'm having some trouble sorting data from a text file by a certain field. Possibly by multiple fields later. The .txt is several thousands of lines of code. I'm brand new to python so my code is probably a bit messy. For example, this is the textfile i would read from:

```
stuff
123 1200 id-aaaa stuart@test.com
322 1812 id-wwww machine-switch@test.com
839 1750 id-wwww gary2-da@test.com
500 0545 id-aaaa abc123@test.com
525 1322 id-bbbb zyx321@test.com
```

my code so far is as follows:

```
filelist = open("info.txt").readlines()
splitlist = list()

class data:
    def __init__(self, eventName, time, identity, domain):
        self.evenName = eventName
        self.time = time
        self.identity = identity
        self.domain = domain

for line in filelist:
    filelist = list.split(', ')
    splitlist.append(filelist)

for column in splitlist:
    if (len(column) > 1): #to skip the first line
        eventName = column[0].strip()
        time = column[1].strip()
        identity = column[2].strip()
        domain = column[3].strip()
```

I want to sort the .txt file line by line by the identity, then maybe by time. I saw that this could be done by classes in the python tutorial, so i'm trying to go that route. Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Is `stuff` *in* the text file, or *the name of* the text file?

Comment: Is there only one such non-data line (ie a header), or might they occur anywhere?

Comment: There is two to be exact. The first and the last line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
with open("info.txt") as inf:
    data = []
    for line in inf:
        line = line.split()
        if len(line)==4:
            data.append(line)

data.sort(key=lambda s:(s[2],s[1]))
```

If you want to get a bit fancier,

```
from collections import namedtuple
Input = namedtuple('Input', ('name', 'time', 'identity', 'domain'))

with open("info.txt") as inf:
    inf.next()  # skip header
    data = [Input(*(line.split()) for line in inf]

data.sort(key=lambda s:(s['identity'],s['time']))
```

If you really, really want to use a class, try:

```
import time

class Data(object):
    def __init__(self, event, time_, identity, domain):
        self.event = event
        self.time = time.strptime(time_, "%H%M")
        self.identity = identity
        self.domain = domain

with open("info.txt") as inf:
    data = []
    for line in inf:
        try:
            data.append(Data(*(line.split()))
        except TypeError:
            # wrong number of arguments (ie header or footer)
            pass

data.sort(key=lambda s:(s.identity,s.time))
```

Comment: Hi Hugh. I seem to be getting a "*** non-keyword arg after keyword arg" error on line data.sort(...

Comment: Sorry - missed a closing-quote on `'time'`.

Comment: It was actually on the first block of code you have written down. Is there a certain library that i need to include to perform .sort?

Comment: Nope, `sort` is built in. I think that either I needed brackets on the `s[2],s[1]` or it was choking on the footer line.

Comment: thanks for all the help hugh!! I referred to this a few times and it helped me understand python syntax and better coding techniques.

Answer (score 0):

The following Python code should put together the information you want, which is then sorted.

```
rows = []
for line in open("info.txt"):
    line = line.split()
    if len(line) != 4:
        continue

    eventName, time, identity, domain = line

    # Add them in the order you want to sort by
    rows.append((identity, time, eventName, domain)) 

rows.sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common mistake made, what you have done it opened it without actually reading the file in the proper syntax, here is what I think:

```
filelist = open("info.txt", "r")
print filelist
filelist.read() # reads the entire file
splitlist = list()

class data:
    def __init__(self, eventName, time, identity, domain):
        self.evenName = eventName
        self.time = time
        self.identity = identity
        self.domain = domain

for line in filelist:
    filelist = list.split(', ')
    splitlist.append(filelist)

for column in splitlist:
    if (len(column) > 1): #to skip the first line
        eventName = column[0].strip()
        time = column[1].strip()
        identity = column[2].strip()
        domain = column[3].strip()
```

Hope that works!
Source: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: `filelist.read()` brings the entire file line in as a single line of data... not what is wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To sort by id then date:

```
text = ["123 1200 id-aaaa stuart@test.com",
        "322 1812 id-wwww machine-switch@test.com",
        "839 1750 id-wwww gary2-da@test.com",
        "500 0545 id-aaaa abc123@test.com",
        "525 1322 id-bbbb zyx321@test.com"]
text = [i.split() for i in text]
text.sort(key=lambda line: (line[2],line[1]))
text = [' '.join(i) for i in text]
print text
#Output:
['500 0545 id-aaaa abc123@test.com', 
'123 1200 id-aaaa stuart@test.com', 
'525 1322 id-bbbb zyx321@test.com', 
'839 1750 id-wwww gary2-da@test.com', 
'322 1812 id-wwww machine-switch@test.com']
```

Comment: If you're going to do `text = sorted(text)`, it would use half as much memory to just `text.sort()`.

Comment: @Hugh Bothwell - thankyou, I have amended, but you were way faster on the trigger!